# Align div right in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way in Bootstrap 3 to right align a div?

I am aware of the offsetting possibilitys but I want to align a formatted div to the right of its container while it should be centered in a fullwidth mobile view. The class 'pull-right' is not working anymore. Did they forgot to replace it or am I missing something obvious?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      left content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <!-- The next div has a background color and its own paddings and should be aligned right-->
      <!-- It is now in the right column but aligned left in that column -->
      <div class="yellow_background">right content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Shure I know how to do this in CSS, but can it be done in pure bootstrap 3?

Comment: pull-right working here...

Answer (score 61):

The class pull-right is still there in Bootstrap 3
See the ['helper classes' here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

pull-right is defined by

```
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

without more info on styles and content, it's difficult to say.

It definitely pulls right in this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/AQErobe/1/edit)
when the page is wider than 990px - which is when the col-md styling kicks in,
Bootstrap 3 being mobile first and all.

**Bootstrap 4**

Note that for Bootstrap 4 .pull-right has been replaced with .float-right
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pull-left-and-pull-right-classes-in-bootstrap-4/#:~:text=pull%2Dright%20classes%20have%20been,based%20on%20the%20Bootstrap%20Grid](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pull-left-and-pull-right-classes-in-bootstrap-4/#:%7E:text=pull%2Dright%20classes%20have%20been,based%20on%20the%20Bootstrap%20Grid).

Answer (score 48):

Do you mean something like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      left content
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

      <div class="yellow-background">
        text
        <div class="pull-right">right content</div>  
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.yellow-background {
  background: blue;
}

.pull-right {
  background: yellow;
}
```

A full example can be found on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/anfhK).

Comment: If I am not wrong the `.yellow-background` class should have `yellow` background but not `blue`.

Answer (score 6):

i think you try to align the content to the right within the div, the div with offset already push itself to the right, here some code and [LIVE sample](http://bootply.com/91916):

FYI: **`.pull-right`** only push the div to the right, but not the content inside the div.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 someclass">
      left content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 someclass">
      <div class="yellow_background totheright">right content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.someclass{ /*this class for testing purpose only*/
    border:1px solid blue;
    line-height:2em;
}

.totheright{ /*this will align the text to the right*/
  text-align:right;
}

.yellow_background{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Another modification:

```
...
<div class="yellow_background totheright">
  <span>right content</span>
  <br/>image also align-right<br/>
  <img width="15%" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
</div>
...
```

hope it will clear your problem

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 4+** has made changes to the utility classes for this. From the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#utilities):

> Added `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` classes for responsive floats and removed `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` since they’re redundant to `.float-left` and `.float-right`.

So use the `.float-right` (or a size equivalent such as `.float-lg-right`) instead of `.pull-right` for your right alignment if you're using a newer Bootstrap version.

Answer (score -4):

Add `offset8` to your class, for example:

```
<div class="offset8">aligns to the right</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and improve its quality by giving more details.