# Make pull-right in the class media

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap version 3.2.1 to edit and delete links was `right`, after the upgrade to 3.3.0 `right` didn't get to level.

Class `media-right` is not suitable for this purpose, it's necessary, that block had no effect on the text below:

http://i.gyazo.com/b114acc7ce9ea2163511e2ebce600136.png

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-body">
    <ul class="list-inline small pull-right">
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758313/align-div-right-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

Put a div with style="clear:both" after ul closing tag.

e.g.

```
<ul class="list-inline small pull-right">
  ....
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```